# What's wrong with this Wheatstone bridge?

Tags: circuit-analysis, wheatstone-bridge, nodal-analysis

[image: image ***1***]

I was trying to solve this unbalanced Wheatstone bridge and found that the current $i$ in the mid wire is **9A** .This result was achieved by using node voltage method.

[image: image ***2***]

Then I rearranged the same circuit to the form shown in the second image.

and at this point I flipped the right half of the circuit so as to obtain the equal resistors on the same side.

[image: image ***3***]

now I again rearranged the circuit as shown.

[image: image ***4***]

Here, the final circuit  is a balanced Wheatstone bridge and thus the current i must be 0.

So clearly something went wrong in there.

I saw a post [a quesiton](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/450682/are-these-two-circuit-equivalent) before this one just to make sure that there is no mistake in rearranging the circuit in the way I have done.

It was answered by the user **PhillipWood** as being correct and was unfortunately put on hold.

So can someone please point out what exactly went wrong with the above method.

Comment: Wheatstone bridges are OPEN between the two arms, not shorted.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Yes, but since the current in the wire will be zero, it should not matter whether it is open or not.

Comment: But you change the resistors position in the bridge. So this is why the circuit has changed and you got a different result.

Comment: When you say "clearly something went wrong in there", what do you mean. What went wrong? It looks like you got the same result I would have, and I don't think anything is wrong with it.

Comment: @ThePhoton Since all I was doing was converting one equivalent circuit to another, and that the middle branch was the same in all these circuits, clearly it should have the same current.

Comment: @harshit54, but the middle branch isn't the same in the two circuits. In one it's across an unbalanced bridge, in the other it's across a balanced bridge.

Comment: @ThePhoton But it is the same branch connecting the two pairs of parallel resistors in both the cases. So the current should have been the same.

Comment: " found that the current $i$ in the mid wire is $3A$"

Comment: When you move the resistors around, you change what the whole circuit is. So even if it's "the same branch", it's a branch in a different circuit. So you can't expect the current to stay the same. (Note: in circuit theory it is the same circuit but the wire isn't actually a branch. Give the wire some nominal resistance \$r\$, maybe 1 mOhm, and now when you move the resistors around it isn't the same circuit any more)

Comment: This question was [also asked on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450822/44126).

Comment: @rob And it was closed because you are the moderator **there**.

Comment: @harshit, if you still want an answer, please edit the question to make clear what you thought was wrong with the result you got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below; just another way to see what's been written in comments.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFXGfc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your first claim in your question is wrong. The current \$i\$ in the top schematic you provide isn't \$9\:\text{A}\$. Instead, it is \$3\:\text{A}\$ (obviously.) You can easily see this by comparing the currents entering and leaving.

(Swapping \$R_1\$ with \$R_2\$ in the above, rightmost case would arrange things so that the currents flowing into and out of the left side would be balanced. Same with the currents flowing into and out of the right side. So in that case there would be no need for a current between the left and right sides because ... well, because you've changed the question being asked now.)

---

Now, let's adjust the above, rightmost schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTHpSX.png)</sup>

Again, without having to introduce any new resistors, you can see the obvious. The \$9\:\text{A}\$ flowing downward from above must obviously also flow along the wire connecting top to bottom. There's no other way for it.

(Swapping \$R_1\$ with \$R_2\$ in this last case makes no difference. The same current sum still must flow through them to ground. So in this case you can swap \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, or swap \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$, without changing the current arriving and leaving through the narrow vertical wire connecting the pairs.)